# Can I use Acrobatics to jump over an enemy that missed me?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, skills, movement

Whether or not a character hits is determined by a roll of a die. Say that they roll low so they failed to hit me, and I want to flip over top of the enemy to get behind them.

Is this legal, and what happens if I roll low?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already. :)

Answer (score 7):

To break this down a little…

If your opponent spends their turn attacking you and misses, then that is it. There are no mechanical effects other than "They do not hit you".

On your turn, you want to move behind them. Let's take a look at a few different ways to achieve that.

The simple way would be to walk around them. To do this there needs to be space around them that you can walk through. You could, GM permitting, narrate this as an acrobatic leap over them. The net result is the same: You end up in the square behind them.

Now there are two situations where the above doesn't fit what you want to do.

- There is no space around them that you could walk though.
- You are trying to gain a mechanical advantage rather than a moment of narrative cool.

First up, the rules as written. They say:

> You can move through a hostile creature's space only if the creature is at least two sizes larger or smaller than you.

So, the short answer is "no".

The GM can make a ruling otherwise though. They would determine the difficulty in leaping over the head of your opponent (which would probably be easier if they were a 4' Goblin than a 7' Drow). You would make the roll, then the GM would determine what happened based on that.

A poor roll could include the opponent blocking your leap, you landing and falling Prone, or you being off balance and your opponent turning an attacking with Advantage on their turn. A good roll could include simply getting behind them, or being able to attack with Advantage yourself.

---

5th edition doesn't have *specific* rules for how difficult a jump should be, but for the sake of interest, let's take a look at the [Jump skill from D&D 3.5](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/jump.htm) which does.

A high jump of 6', without a 20' run-up, has a target number of 48. i.e. really, really hard.

5th edition tends to have lower target numbers, but the sort of jump you are looking to achieve would probably require magical assistance.

Comment: 5e does away with skill checks for jumping; by default, you can jump up to a number of feet equal to one-half of 3 + your strength modifier, or double that if you have 10 feet of run-up. For a standing high jump over a six foot creature, you would need a strength modifier of +9 (corresponding to a strength score of 28-29)

Answer (score 3):

There is an optional rule written in the DMG (pg 272), ['Tumble'](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#Tumble), wherein a character can:

> As an action or a bonus action, the tumbler makes a Dexterity (Acrobatics) check contested by the hostile creature’s Dexterity (Acrobatics) check. If the tumbler wins the contest, it can move through the hostile creature’s space once this turn.

It does not mention any negative outcome if the contest is failed outright by the PC. Of course, in the event of a tie the situation remains the same as before the check.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] for further guidance.

Comment: This is a good find you have. I've gone ahead to edit in the exact quote you are referring to, which is acceptable practice here. Thanks for finding this for us!

Comment: @Pyrotechnical: The wording in your quote didn't quite match that in the DMG, so I've fixed the quote. :)